# Is wrapping code into a function that doesn't need to be, bad in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Many many times on a page I will have to set post and get values in PHP like this

**I just want to know if it is better to just continue doing it the way I have above or if performance would not be touched by adding it into a function like in the code below?**

This would make it much easiar to write code but at the expense of making extra function calls on the page.

I have all the time in the world so making the code as fast as possible is more important to me then making it "easiar to write or faster to develop"

Appreciate any advice and please nothing about whichever makes it easier to develop, I am talking pure performance here =)

```
<?php
function arg_p($name, $default = null) {
    return (isset($_GET[$name]))?$_GET[$name]:$default;
}

$pagesize = arg_p('pagesize', 10);

$pagesize = (isset($_GET['pagesize'])) ? $_GET['pagesize'] : 10;

?>
```

Comment: You may have a lot of time, but would you rather spend it fixing bugs or adding new features? Maintainability counts!

Comment: Are you seriously worried about the performance overhead of an additional function call?  You solved all your database, http request, minification, compression, and caching problems already?

Comment: @jfar never said I was worried but yeah 70% slower is worth noticing instead of straight up ignoring a fact, I guess you would need to know more about the size and traffic of the application first though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *have all the time in the world*, why don't you just test it?

```
<?php
// How many iterations?
$iterations = 100000;

// Inline
$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);
for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
  $pagesize = (isset($_GET['pagesize'])) ? $_GET['pagesize'] : 10;
}
$time_spent = microtime(TRUE) - $timer_start;
printf("Inline: %.3fs\n", $time_spent);

// By function call
function arg_p($name, $default = null) {
  return (isset($_GET[$name])) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
}

$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);
for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
  $pagesize = arg_p('pagesize', 10);
}
$time_spent = microtime(TRUE) - $timer_start;
printf("By function call: %.3fs\n", $time_spent);
?>
```

On my machine, this gives pretty clear results in favor of inline execution by a factor of almost 10. But you need a lot of iterations to really notice it.

(I would still use a function though, even if me answering this shows that I have time to waste ;)

Comment: thanks, using that shows about a 70% slow down by using the function instead. in a large scale system I think that is worth noticing

Comment: @jasondavis: 70% in and of itself is worth noticing but how much of your total runtime is taken up by those calls? If it's more than a couple of percent, you've probably got bigger problems. 

In reality, if I were that concerned with it, I'd probably be suggesting a single function at the script start that 'standardises' my GET parameter and then from there, just drag from GET directly (if that makes sense... basically ensure that your GET array is populated correctly with defaults if need be, then never test it again).

Answer (score 3):

Sure you'll probably get a performance benefit from not wrapping it into a function. But would it be noticeable? Not really.

Your time is worth more than the small about of CPU resources you'd save.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the difference in speed would be noticeable unless you are doing it many hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2):

Function call is a performance hit, but you should also think about maintainability - wrapping it in the function could ease future changes (and copy-paste is bad for that).

Comment: Well, I've never really been on 4chan. But, if "copypasta" is so bad, then I'll change it.

Comment: "copypasta" existed before 4chan, btw. Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst performance wouldn't really be affected, anything that takes code out of the html stream the better.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a thousand calls to your `arg_p()` you wouldn't be able to measure —let alone *notice*— the difference in performance. The time you will spend typing the extra "inline" code plus the time you will spend whenever you'll have to duplicate the changes to every inlined copy plus the added complexity and higher probability of typo or random error will cost you more than the unmeasurable performance improvement. In fact, that time could be spent on optimizing what really counts such as improving your database design, profile your code to find the areas that really affect the generation time, etc...

You'll be better off keeping your code clean. It will save you time that you can in turn invest into optimizing what really counts.